# Can the Chinese Remainder Theorem be proved for a commutative ring without unity? Or if $I+J \neq R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I apologize for this not being a more specific question. I am just wondering what conditions are "necessary" for the Chinese Remainder Theorem to hold true. I know that we need a surjective homomorphism, and I'm wondering if this is possible to find or not if we have a commutative ring without unity, or if $R \neq I + J$ for two ideals $I$ and $J?$

Comment: Are you asking in what generality $R/(I\cap J)$ and $R/I \times R/J$ are isomorphic as rings? Or what statement do you have in mind? Something like $\varphi:R\rightarrow S$ a homomorphism and $R/ker(\varphi)$ isomorphic to $Im(\varphi)$?

Comment: The first one, in what generality is $R/(I∩J) = R/I×R/J$ true? Is it ever true for a commutative ring without unity, and not equal to the direct sum of the two ideals?

Comment: With the natural maps $R/(I\cap J)\cong R/I\times R/J$  iff $R\to R/I\times R/J$ is surjective iff $R=I+J$, no need that $R$ is unital, not even commutative.